# Connecting different flows according to the situation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

There is a flow structure that works correctly as the following.
When flow1 is finished, flow2 starts to work.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

val flow_1 = flowOf("loading_1", "loading_1", "success_1").onEach { delay(100) }

val flow_2 = flowOf("loading_2", "loading_2", "success_2").onEach { delay(200) }

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit>  {
   
    flowOf(
        flow_1
            .onEach { if (it == "failure_1") throw Exception("Failed!") }
            .retry(3), 
        flow_2
    ).flattenConcat()
    .catch { println("Failed with $it") }
    .collect {
        println("Result $it")
    }
}
```

For example, if there is another flow, if flow_1 fails, flow_2 will run. If flow_1 is successful, flow_3 will run, is it possible?

```
val flow_1 = flowOf("loading_1", "loading_1", "success_1").onEach { delay(100) }
val flow_2 = flowOf("loading_2", "loading_2", "success_2").onEach { delay(200) }
val flow_3 = flowOf("loading_3", "loading_3", "success_3").onEach { delay(200) }


flow_1, flow_3 will run in sequence(because flow_1 will be finished with success)
```

```
val flow_1 = flowOf("loading_1", "loading_1", "error_1").onEach { delay(100) }
val flow_2 = flowOf("loading_2", "loading_2", "success_2").onEach { delay(200) }
val flow_3 = flowOf("loading_3", "loading_3", "success_3").onEach { delay(200) }


flow_1, flow_2 will run in sequence(because flow_1 will be finished with error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is complicated enough that it should be done with a `flow` builder instead of using flow operators. Like this:

```
flow {
    class Flow1FailureException: Exception("Failed!")
    val flow_1WithRetry = flow_1
        .onEach { if (it == "failure_1") throw Flow1FailureException() }
        .retry(3)
    try {
        emitAll(flow_1WithRetry)
        emitAll(flow_3)
    } catch (e: Flow1FailureException) {
        emitAll(flow_2)
    }
}
    .collect {
        println("Result $it")
    }
```

Edit: without throwing example:

```
flow {
    val numRetries = 3
    var failure1Count = 0
    val flow1WithRetries = 
        flowOf(*Array(numRetries) { flow_1 })
            .flattenConcat()
            .onEach { if(it == "failure_1") failure1Count++ }
            .transformWhile {
                emit(it)
                it != "success_1"
            }
    emitAll(flow1WithRetries)
    emitAll(if(failure1Count == numRetries) flow_2 else flow_3)
}
    .collect {
        println("Result $it")
    }
```

Comment: By the way, I should have introduced a specific Exception like this in my answer to your previous question, because it is terrible practice to catch generic `Exception`. You should always catch specifically the types of exceptions you're expecting might happen and let others bubble up.

Comment: i guess there is no way to achieve this without throwing exception. For example, I will update the db according to the result from flow_1 and send a message from ble according to the other situation. This scenario can be easily done based on your answer.  But I was wondering if it could be done without throwing an error.

Comment: It can be done without throwing by using an external variable, but the code would be more convoluted, especially if you want the repeated retries. What’s the point in avoiding throwing? It’s all internal to this function anyway.